# Merge Wordpress comments with Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

Am required to integrate the Facebook comments on a wordpress blog... There are no issues there ( ran a few tests locally and everything turned out alright ). 
The problem appears when I'm asked to keep the current Wordpress comments, but under the facebook layout. Basically the client doesn't want to lose the current comments, but in the same time I can't keep the wordpress comments either. Everything has to be faceook...

Any ideas? Any suggestions? Is this possible at all ( I 'googled' everything related to this question, but there was no answer ).

P.S.: how did Techcrunch manage to do this ( or they kept the comments from their facebook page? )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The plugin [Facebook Comments for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/) is doing what you are looking for :

- users can post with their Facebook account (and cross-post on their wall)
- users can post with standard Wordpress comments
- comments from both sources are merged
- and a lot of cool features the Facebook comments plugin miss (chronological order, email notification, cross-post all comments to a user page, etc.)